# Objective-C, why do these NSArrays not match?

Tags: objective-c, comparison, nsarray

I have two NSArrays that I'm comparing — in the NSLog output they look identical, yet they don't equal each other somehow. If I convert the NSArray to an NSString I get the same exact result. Comparing them to themselves will be equal. How can I determine why one and two aren't equal? thank you.

```
- (void)confused:(NSArray *)two {

    NSArray *one = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"16777223", @"7", nil];
    NSArray *two = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/path/to/bundle"] executableArchitectures];

    // NSArray "two" shows as 16277223, 7 in NSLog

    if ([two firstObjectCommonWithArray:(NSArray *)one])
    {
        NSLog(@"- it's equal %@ %@", one, two);
        // if array one matches array two then this will output
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"- it's NOT equal %@ %@", one, two);
    }

    return;
}
```

Here's the output from console:

```
myApp (
    16777223,
    7
)
myApp (
    16777223,
    7
)
myApp - it's NOT equal (
    16777223,
    7
)(
    16777223,
    7
)
```

Comment: Can you include the creation of `two`?

Comment: it's directly related to my other question `'[[NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/path/to/bundle"] executableArchitectures]'`; so the values of NSArray one in the above example would be `@"16777223",@"7",nil`

Comment: Oh. That method returns an array of `NSNumber`, not `NSString`. That's your problem.

Comment: Yep, if the object types are different they aren't likely to compare the same, even if they produce the same `description` dump.

Comment: Okay, I've updated the question with how NSArray two is created. So the question really is how to represent NSArray one so that it would equal two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-[NSBundle executableArchitectures]` returns an array of `NSNumber` objects, not `NSString` objects, so the array you're passing in doesn't have strings in it. If you change

```
NSArray *one = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"16777223",@"7", nil];
```

to

```
NSArray *one = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:NSBundleExecutableArchitectureX86_64], 
                                         [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:NSBundleExecutableArchitectureI386], 
                  nil];
```

your code should work.

Comment: wow, so the mach-o part is built in? i had no idea, very cool. i'm going to try it right now — thanks!

Comment: You mean `NSBundleExecutableArchitectureX86_64`? Those are just names that you imported. They're defined in NSBundle.h, right above where `executableArchitectures` is declared.

Comment: When you're using the values from an `enum` like this, it's always preferable to refer to them by their name, not value -- it improves readability and guards against possible changes in the value (however unlikely).

Comment: That makes sense; for some reason though i'm getting the same result with it not being equal. Maybe I'm not comparing the values properly? I've even tried `if (two == one) { NSLog(@"Equal: %@%@", one, two);` but it doesn't register as being equal. it's got to be something i'm missing obviously? thanks

Comment: `==` compares the `NSArray` objects' locations in memory; those definitely won't be equal. `firstObjectCommonWithArray:` or `[one isEqual:two]` should both work, though. Are they not?

Comment: ah, firstObjectCommonWithArray is not equal (no idea why), but `[one isEqual:two]` is equal. It sort of reminds me of P=NP heh. thanks very much for helping me ;-)

Comment: `firstObjectCommonWithArray :`returns the first object that is the same in the array, it is *not* for equality checks.

Comment: @borrrden, thanks - it's nice to know there are so many helpful people to explain these things, i very much appreciate it.

Comment: It should still not be returning `nil`, though. @borrrden

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes, but that's another story ^^;  I didn't want OP to think that once it didn't return `nil` that the arrays were equal.  It would only prove that they had one item in common.

Comment: @bor: Fair enough. It seemed like that was the original intent  -- to find the match -- but I may have misread.